# Не добавляются данные в массив postgresql с помощью psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, aiogram, psycopg2

Хочу сделать корзину для телеграмм бота с помощью массива в postgresql, используя код(показан ниже) в столбец korzina(тип столбца - character varying[]) не добавляется айди товара, хотя должен. Буду рад если подскажете как изменить код чтобы все работало, спасибо!

```
@router.callback_query(text='tovar_001')
async def tovar_001(callback: CallbackQuery):
id = ['001']
us_id = int(callback.message.from_user.id)
connection.cursor(f'SELECT array_append(korzina,{id}) FROM bot_users WHERE user_id={us_id}')
connection.commit()

await callback.message.answer(text='<b>Товар добавлен в корзину</b>')
```

Comment: Объясните подробнее, что вызывает у вас затруднение? Что в коде не работает?

Comment: не добавляется айди товара в массив корзины

Comment: когда вывожу таблицу в поле корзина выводит None

Comment: Мне кажется Вам стоит детальнее изучить SQL. Если вам нужно добавить товар в базу данных, нужно использовать INSERT, а не SELECT